# Type geometry in mysql -> AsText doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I altered my db with a new column with type geometry. And then I am getting this error when I am trying to select something from my db. With select all and also with select of only one specific column (name = location).

Looks like every time it wanted to select the geometry type, even when I don't want to select it.

```
QueryFailedError: ER_SP_DOES_NOT_EXIST: FUNCTION service.AsText does not exist
```

I have this query in my nestjs typeorm.

```
const user = this.usersRepository
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .where('user.id = :userId')
    .getOne();
```

This is part of my package.json

```
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
"mysql2": "^2.3.3",
"mysql8": "^2.17.3",
```

I have MySQL 8 and in google I found out this

```
The AsText function was deprecated in MySQL 5.7.6 and removed in MySQL 8.0.
```

What can I do to remove this error?

Comment: Use [ST_AsText](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html#function_st-astext). Or create user-defined function AsText in your database which calls ST_AsText.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have a solution.
I added legacySpatialSupport to app.module.ts

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  legacySpatialSupport: false,
```

Geometry is a spatial type in DB.
So false means that I don't want to do anything with it.

It is useful when I am doing select only on specific non-spatial columns. Therefore I don't need to edit my older select query code.